# Blade @props overrides passed attribute value

Tags: laravel, components, laravel-blade

I am making a component based data table I have a `Table` component:

```
<h2 class="my-6 text-2xl font-semibold text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200">
    {{ $title }}
</h2>
<h4 class="mb-4 text-lg font-semibold text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-300">
    {{ $sub_title }}
</h4>
<div class="w-full overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-xs">
    <div class="w-full overflow-x-auto">
        <table class="w-full whitespace-no-wrap">
            <thead>
                <tr
                    class="text-xs font-semibold tracking-wide text-left text-gray-500 uppercase border-b dark:border-gray-700 bg-gray-50 dark:text-gray-400 dark:bg-gray-800">
                    {{ $head }}
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="bg-white divide-y dark:divide-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800">
                {{ $body }}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also I have a head component for table headings:

```
@props(['sortable' => null,'direction' => null,])
<th {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'px-4 py-3 text-xs'])->only('class') }}>
    @unless($sortable)
        <span>
            {{ $slot }}
        </span>
    @else
        <span>
            <button class="flex items-center justify-center">
                <span>{{ $slot }}</span>
                @if ($direction === 'asc')
                    <span>
                        <x-icon.arrow-up />
                    </span>
                @elseif($direction === 'desc')
                    <span>
                        <x-icon.arrow-down />
                    </span>
                @else
                    <span class="opacity-75 hover:opacity-100">
                        <x-icon.arrow-up-down />
                    </span>
                @endif
            </button>
        </span>
    @endunless
</th>
```

I am rendering in my view like this:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <x-table>
        <x-slot name="title">
            Dashboard
        </x-slot>
        <x-slot name="sub_title">
            new
        </x-slot>
        <x-slot name="head">
            <x-table.head sortable>#</x-table.head>
            <x-table.head sortable>title</x-table.head>
            <x-table.head>Actions</x-table.head>
        </x-slot>
        <x-slot name="body">
            <x-table.row>
                <x-table.cell>There</x-table.cell>
                <x-table.cell>There</x-table.cell>
                <x-table.cell>There</x-table.cell>
            </x-table.row>
        </x-slot>
    </x-table>
@endsection
```

All component classes are the default generated class.
The exact problem is the `$sortable` variable is always `null` and unable to override the default value from the component x-tag as expected.

**PS1:**
I am repeating the code from:
[A Simple Table](https://laravel-livewire.com/screencasts/s7-simple-table) livewire screencasts.

Comment: Is it an anonymous component and is it located in the `components/head` directory?

Comment: @ArturCapraro No it is an ordinary component located `components/table/head.blade.php` file.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@unless(!$sortable)` of simply use `@if($sortable)`? If you simple print `{{ $sortable }}`, what value does it return?

Comment: It returns `null` at any condition.

Comment: Did you create the component with artisan command `php artisan make:component ComponentName`?

Comment: Yes, actually `php artisan make:component Table/Head`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225464/discussion-between-eamirgh-and-artur-capraro).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Hanley at livewire discord community,
The solution is that to delete the generated class and make the component anonymous.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not an anonymous component, you must pass the props through the constructor of the component class, located in the `app/view/components` folder, something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class Head extends Component
{

    public $sortable;

    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($sortable = false)
    {
        $this->sortable = $sortable;
    }
    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represents the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.table.head');
    }
}
```

Or symple make the component anonimous deleting his class.